# pre_get_posts post_meta event

Tags: custom-taxonomy, pre-get-posts, custom-post-type-archives

I wish `pre_get_posts` to filter posts that appear in the `archive-events.php` and `taxonomy-eventcat.php` templates.

I have a `post_meta` in use named `o_event_start` that stores a value in [**DATETIME**](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/datetime.html) (2014-12-31 21:30:00) *format* and I wish to show all events (cpt) that

1. <s>are happening today (only on page 1)</s> using **WP_Query**
2. <s>are happening tomorrow (only on page 1)</s> using **WP_Query**
3. are happening in the future but not **today** or **tomorrow** (paged)
4. already happened (paged)

3 and 4 need to happen in the main loop and I was pointed twards `pre_get_posts` but I got lost. Anybody knows how?

And I forgot to mention: How do you order all of them by `o_event_start` (descending for past and ascending for future).

Comment: Not sure about what you meant by striking parts out there?.. :) Also you have two sets of pagination — future and past, how do you imagine them working? Date descending?

Comment: @Rarst meaning they have been dealt with using WP_Query because they are only displayed on the first page. As pagination goes: For future events ascending dates and for past events descending dates. I have a query var that tells me if I need to show future or past.

Answer (score 1):

If you have store date different then timestamp it will be VERY hard to do this.

To get this if is timestamp stored, you need add "meta_query" like this:

```
add_action('pre_get_posts', 'my_pre_get_posts');
function my_pre_get_posts($query)
{
    $offest = 0;// you must count this to avoid today and tomorrow
    $query->set(
        'meta_query',
        array(
            'relation' => 'AND',
            array(
                'key' => 'o_event_start',
                'value' => time() + $offest,
                'type' => 'numeric',
                'compare' => '>',
            )
        )
    );
 }
```

$offest for 0:01 is easy 2*24*60*60-1 (two-days*24h*60m*60s - 1s ) for other you must cont from the current time.

Comment: How about pagination of the results?

Comment: And I need it in datetime. I have edited my question above.

Comment: I fixed everything except `orderby`. How can you order by post meta asc or desc?

Comment: Thank you for your help. I managed to find what I needed.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to Marcin I managed to solve all the problems.

```
function o_pre_get_posts_events($query)
{
    if (is_post_type_archive("post")) { // I need this for all my other cpts, but not for post
        return;
    }

    // we get the day of today
    $today = date("Y-m-d");
    // we add to it (2 days for me)
    $two_days = date("Y-m-d", strtotime($today . " + 2 days"));

    // if events are past or future
    $compare = (get_query_var('past') == true) ? "<" : ">";

    // order desc for past and asc for future
    $order = (get_query_var('past') == true) ? "desc" : "asc";
    $query->set(
        'meta_query',
        array(
            'relation' => 'AND',
            array(
                'key' => 'o_event_start',
                'value' => $two_days,
                'type' => 'datetime',
                'compare' => $compare,
            )
        )
    );

    // pagination
    $query->set('paged', get_query_var('paged'));
    $query->set('posts_per_page', 6);

    // ordering
    $query->set('meta_key', 'o_event_start');
    $query->set('orderby', 'o_event_start');
    $query->set('order', $order);
}

add_action('pre_get_posts', 'o_pre_get_posts_events');
```